# Выбор фреймворка для отрисовки GUI (Qt, WPF, WinForms)

Tags: c++, qt, winforms, gui, opencv

У меня есть проект, основная цель которого - отслеживание объектов на видео с помощью алгоритмов оптического потока. Пишу его на C++ с использованием OpenCV в Visual Studio.

Мне понадобится вывод изображения в окно, и небольшие функции плеера (кнопки перемотки видео, паузы и тп). Быстродействие важнее "красоты" интерфейса.

Что лучше использовать для GUI? QtGui, WPF или Windows Forms? Или может быть есть какие-то другие варианты?

Comment: WPF и Windows Forms - это не С++

Comment: ну wpf да, но winforms есть и на плюсах

Comment: winforms есть на с++-cli

Comment: так всё-таки, что лучше использовать, если важно именно быстродействие? в принципе, нет особой проблемы в переписании кода на C#

Comment: Если важно быстродействие, то лучше не использовать ничего из вышеперечисленного, а запилить что-нибудь на directx opengl

Comment: а если выбирать из этих трёх вариантов?)